# How to plot this direction field in Maple.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

$y^{\prime}=ay+b$ where $a,b$ are positive numbers.

I know how to plot this if I have exact values for both $a$ and $b$, but how to see the difference as either/both $a$ and $b$ change?

I understand the problem mathematically, but how to show this with maple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
restart:    
Explore(
     DEtools[dfieldplot](diff(y(x),x) = a*y(x)+b, y(x), x= -2..2, y= -2..2),
     parameters= [a= 0.0..2.0, b= 0.0..2.0]
);
```

Then use your mouse to control the sliders for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Error, (in DEtools/dfieldplot) vars must be declared as a list, e.g. [x(t),y(t),...]  is what I get unless I click the skip box on $x$.  why is that?

Comment: It sounds like you have some extraneous variables defined. Try doing a `restart:`. I've updated my Answer to include this.